# Actionbar dropdown list

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Seeing many solutions for a dropdown list in the action bar, I found this one looking quite simple and easy to use. But ... it has a flaw.

First pressing the dropdown (in the actionbar) gives: 
unregisterIRListener() is called  (6 times)

Selecting 1 menu item gives: 
sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

And of course no action is started.

Can you please help me solving this flaw? It will learn me more about Android programming and may be this easy solution can be used often.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {
public static String[] actionBarActions = new String[] { "Location tracker" };
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main);

    // Actionbar dropdown adapter 
    ArrayAdapter<String> actionBarAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( getActionBar().getThemedContext(),  
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actionBarActions);

    // Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar
    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    // Setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for the actionbar
    getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks( actionBarAdapter, this);
}

 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        System.out.println( " *** Menu item pressed "  + actionBarActions[itemPosition]); 
        return false; 
 }
}
```

Comment: You didn't use the @Override annotation at onNavigationItemSelected(..). Try adding it.

Comment: Aashir, YES !!!! 

THis works!

Comment: Great to hear, answer posted. Accept it so others facing a similar issue may resolve theirs.

Comment: @Aashir I don't see how the `@Override` annotation solved the problem. Its purpose is to add a compiler check to ensure you're overriding the correct method, it doesn't do anything at runtime. `onNavigationItemSelected()` seemed to have been properly overridden from the beginning.

Comment: Its not as much 'checking' as telling the compiler to override the method from the parent class. As it wasn't overridden, it wasn't automatically called by the framework.

Comment: @Aashir That's incorrect. First of all, `@Override` was introduced in java 6, overriding a method has been part of Java long before that. Secondly, refer to the [Java tutorial section on annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html). It says *While it is not required to use this annotation when overriding a method, it helps to prevent errors. If a method marked with `@Override` fails to correctly override a method in one of its superclasses, the compiler generates an error.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use the `@Override` annotation at `onNavigationItemSelected()`. Try adding it and it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Aashir --> it now works.

I forgot to add the @Override. So, the code is:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    System.out.println( " *** Menu item pressed "  + actionBarActions[itemPosition]); 
    return false; 
}
```